# Outbox message not being sent

Tags: android

In my app I want to keep track on sms sending. In case of sms does not sent due to network failure(No signal).

I managed to put sms in outbox :

```
    private void putoutbox(String addr,String msg) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
      values.put("address", addr);
           values.put("body", msg);
           getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse("content://sms/Outbox"), values);
    }
```

sms is being shown in default message folder with status sending
but sms never sent
I also tried

```
content://sms/failed
```

and it also does not send sms.
Please tell me what I am missing.

Comment: Simply adding an entry into the table will not make the Native SMS Messenger send the entry. There are other columns that need to be filled and also "content://sms/" is not standard and will break on some phones.

Comment: @st0le what are the other attributes i need to set and i want to run on the a specific device(client req) and it is working

Comment: Check out this [file](http://android-smspopup.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/SMSPopup/src/net/everythingandroid/smspopup/util/SmsMessageSender.java) in SMSPopup project, it's got all you need

Comment: @st0le Thank you,it looks promising I am trying it and will get back with result

Comment: @st0le i set all the attributes but same story happens, i got stucked with thread_id attribute. I think i m not getting this right way

Comment: I haven't really worked on it but i remember it was simply a number assigned to each sms conversation on the phone. That's all i know.

Comment: @st0le Sorry for late reply. somehow i put the date attribute wrong(that was 2-3 days later) so when the specified date comes all the outbox message start sending(which makes my balance nill hahaha) and thank you for your help ,you give me right guidance

Comment: @dheeraj Perhaps you could create an answer and accept it so this shows up as "answered"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank  you all for helping me

as st0le gives a very useful link [here](http://android-smspopup.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/SMSPopup/src/net/everythingandroid/smspopup/util/SmsMessageSender.java) one must have to provide all seven attribute 
unfortunately i can not show the code for that,but it will work if you restart your phone